# Servlet Spring MVC java - Can't Access Controller and View

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm **new to Spring MVC java**.

**Configuration** ( what I've done )

- import spring library
- import common-logging
- Tomcat server ( can access localhost:8080 )

**Problem encounter**

I can access **index.jsp** under **web-content** without problem, but when access **hello.jsp** under **WEB-INF**, server show **HTTP STATUS 404**, url was stopped at  http://localhost:8080/APK_downloader/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp[image: problem image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

  <display-name>APK downloader</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml** (servlet configuration xml)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="solutionView"/>

    <bean id="HanlderMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**DBController.java** ( java resources class )

```
package solutionView;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public class DBController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getModelView(){
        System.out.println("helllo");    // check point
        return new ModelAndView("hello");
    }

}
```

**hello.jsp** ( view jsp )

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can not access WEB-INF files directly .try to access http://localhost:8080/APK_downloader/hello

Comment: Please read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904298/why-jsp-files-inside-web-inf-folder-works-but-placed-under-a-folder-under-web), it'll help you a lot.

Comment: @rupesh_padhye I don't want access with url, is any way to access jsp through controller ?

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that you can't access **WEB-INF** folder directly . So `http://localhost:8080/APK_Downloader/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp` will not work

Second you annotated your handler with  `@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")`  as well as your controller class. So the complete url for accessing the handler is

```
http://localhost:8080/APK_Downloader/hello/hello
```

if you directly want to access the method relative to your context just remove 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")` from controller

and also change your view resolver defination

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

to

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

you missed the jsp part in prefix

Answer (score 2):

Change your **spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

From

```
<bean id="HanlderMapping" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
```

To

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

> Because you are using annotation-driven MVC controllers (i.e.
>   @RequestMapping, @Controller). That's why you need to add that above
>   statement in **spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove this line and direct write /hello in url string it is redirect to hello.jsp page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
```

Comment: Thanks for correction, but it can't open as default hello.jsp
But it help in future to redirect url page.

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    Publicpublic class DBController {
          }

Answer (score 0):

You can't access files under `WEB-INF` directly you have to let the servlet to manage that.

As per the URL mapping, you need to know that the mapping of a `method` comes after the mapping of its owning  `Controller`

For Example :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public class DBController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getModelView(){
        System.out.println("helllo");    // check point
        return new ModelAndView("hello");
    }

}
```

**Means** that the `getModelView()` will respond the the following URL :

```
http://localhost:8080/APK_downloader/hello/hello
```

to remove the duplicated hello you have two choices, either remove the

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
```

from the controller , or keep it and change your method to the following:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller class this way :

```
@Controller
public class DBController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String displayHelloPage(){
       return "hello";

       }

}
```

Now, how to call this URL. `localhost:8080/context_path/hello.`
You must check if you have context path in eclipse set, in Servers. If Context-path is `/`, then just `localhost:8080/hello` . I hope this helps, if not, lemme know, I will remove my answer.

Comment: You let me know context path could change from **project => properties => web project settings => Context root** Thanks.

Comment: But I told you it's in Servers, as I use Intellij Idea, I couldn't remember where exactly it was/is.

Comment: Then your config must be wrong, edit your main post and paste spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml and web.xml, complete.