# Spring MVC controller not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

Iam getting a `HTTP staus  404` error when i click submit on the login page . It seems like the controller does not get invoked at all (i tried placing debug points in the controller but the execution flow doesn't hit that point).

[image: My project structure is as follows]

My controller class

```
package web;
org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processCredentials(@RequestParam("userName")String userName,@RequestParam("password")String password) {
        String message = "Invalid credentials";
        if(!userName.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {
            if(userName.equals(password)) {
                message = "Welcome " + userName + "!!";
            }
        }
        return new ModelAndView("results","message",message);
    }
}
```

Application context

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="web" >
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property
            name="prefix"
            value="/" >
        </property>
        <property
            name="suffix"
            value=".jsp" >
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>retrospective</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/retrospective/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Simple Login Application Using Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" border="0" style="border:1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <td>User Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.neerav</groupId>
  <artifactId>retrospective</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>retrospective Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>  
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>  
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>  
        <version>2.2.2</version>  
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>retrospective</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source> <!-- yours Java version -->
                <target>1.7</target> <!-- yours Java version -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When i start the server , i can see the controller and the method name but after pressing submit on the login page controller method is not called .
Could anyone tell me what exactly is the issue ?
[![Console of the browser submission][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Does your url have the `/retrospective/*` part defiend in web.xml?!

Comment: could you just show us the console of the browser when you post the login form, it seems that the form's action is incorrect.

Comment: @KLajdPaja yes it has please have a look

Comment: IMO,I have just find that your `RequestMapping` for your controller, you had annotated the controller with `@RequestMapping("/login")`, and the method annotated with `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`,so the method's value is default '/'.As a result, the request url should be added with '/', the full url is http://localhost:8080/retrospective/login//

Comment: @DemonColdmist Are you trying to suggest what Daryl has posted as an answer ,if yes than i tried that it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should try this url localhost:8080/retrospective/retrospective/login

Comment: Try to not using words like `maybe` or `try` as your answers. A good answer shoul provide concrete information about solution and some explanation about it (if it's necessary ofcourse).

Comment: do you put your project into root directory?You have defined <finalName>retrospective</finalName> in pom. I think localhost:8080/retrospective is just the project url and you should add a retrospective to go into springmvc and then login. So I think it should be like this action=retrospective/login

Answer (score 0):

i think you will set

```
public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 String message = "Invalid credentials";
    if(!userName.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {
        if(userName.equals(password)) {
            message = "Welcome " + userName + "!!";
        }
    }
    return new ModelAndView("results","message",message);
}
```

}

its return on results page. check you have a results.jsp page or not?

Comment: I tried ur approach it is not working , any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You might need to move your jsp file under WEB-INF/jsp like folder directory. Once I got the same kind of issue and solved like that. Then you may need to configure your InternalResourceViewResolver bean as follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

You may want to look at this:
 [Why jsp files inside WEB-INF folder works , but placed under a folder under WEB-INF doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904298/why-jsp-files-inside-web-inf-folder-works-but-placed-under-a-folder-under-web)

Comment: i tried ur approach , it is not working any other suggestions

Comment: I think you will need to create results.jsp file which will get invoked after pressing the submit button. There you can handle what to do with your model attributes.

Comment: Try to add bean "id" attribute as "jspViewResolver" for InternalResourceViewResolver by the way in dispatcher-servlet.xml file.