# ModelAndView not finding Url

Tags: java, spring

The page that I want to show exists in:

java/resources/src/main/webapp/etwebTmpl/login/reset.jsp

I am using ModelAndView when I went to display it I obtained this error 
message /project/WEB-INF/views/etwebTmpl/login/reset.jsp 
resources is not available

How can I fix this? I mean how can I set modelAndView to the right Url

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reset", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayPage(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam("token") String token) {


    modelAndView.setViewName("/etwebTmpl/login/reset");
    return modelAndView  ;

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default Spring looks at `WEB-INF/views` directory for view files.

You can simply fix your problem by moving the jsp files into `WEB_INF/views`.

Else, you can configure your `jspViewResolver` to some other path. In you case it should be `/` which is the root of `webapp` folder.

You can configure it like,

```
    <bean id="jspViewResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResource‌​ViewResolver" 
p:prefix="/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

in your `diapatcher-servlet.xml` file.

For further reference, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925021/2169998).

Comment: Really thanks for your response.  I 'm using spring boot then i will see how to configure diapatcher-servlet.xml thanks again :)